# chromedriver.exe stopped working issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using a windows client to perform UI automated tests. each time i start the test using cmd or eclipse the browser opens up and goes to the given url but it does not continue, instead, a small window is opened with "Chromedriver.exe stopped working" message on it. how can I solve this issue?
I am using on this windows client : python 2.7.15, selenium 3.5.0 , robot framework 3.0.2,windows 7 professional , and chrome
P.S. : I already tried upgrading and downgrading both chrome and chrome driver,
also, used selenium 3.13.0 then downgraded again to selenium 3.5.0.

Comment: Can you update the question with `code trials` and the entire `traceback` for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem . Chrome driver version in the system was an old one despite the fact that i downloaded the newest. I managed to delete the old one from my system. It works fine now

Comment: still can't do it :) 11 hrs remain

Comment: yeah the waiting time is 48 hours